# Finding maximum input (time complexity)

Tags: time-complexity

Assume a computer operating at 1GHz speeds — i.e. it executes 10^9 instructions/second. For each of the following time complexities, what is the largest size input n that could be completely processed in 1 week?

```
a) n²
b) n³
c) 2^n
```

This is homework. I don't need the answer I just don't know how to start the problem. Can someone please show me how to solve the first one. I could then figure out the rest. Thank you!

The way I see it is take 10^9 and subtract 10² to get the maximum input but that seems too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hours in a day, 7 days in a week. That's 604800 seconds.

If you can execute 10^9 instructions per second, you can execute 604800*10^9 instructions per week - that's 6.048*10^14.

The square root of 6.048*10^14 is 24,592,681, i.e. we can process 24,592,681^2 instructions in a week, so we can process 24,592,681 sized input if it is n^2 time complexity.

The rest are pretty similar.

Comment: what about nlogn time complexity

Comment: This answer is not correct. Time complexities say *nothing* about absolute running times. For an algorithm that has a O(n²) time complexity you cannot assume that there is such a ratio between different samples, since big O only tells us something about asymptotic behaviour, not about behaviour for some finite samples.