# FInd maximum input data for the given time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

An algorithm takes 0.5 milliseconds to process 100 input data.
Find the maximum input data in one minute when time complexity of the algorithm  is

```
O(nlogn)
```

Comment: There is no way to determine this. The one who designed this question does not fully understand what time complexity is about.

Comment: @trincot sorry my answer makes no sense to you?

Comment: @trincot well it was my data structure teacher :)

Comment: Be gentle with them ;-)

Comment: Does your data structure teacher have examples of how to solve this kind of problem? Because it makes no sense. Big-O notation is very lossy - it conveys only asymptotic ranking, not anything that be used directly in calculating real runtimes, especially not from one data point. Do you have more data points? Any answer is potentially valid. Who's to say the algorithm won't take one minute on 101 data inputs? Who's to say the algorithm won't take .001 nanoseconds on 102 data inputs? You might have a bad teacher here, or there's a lot missing to this problem that you've left out.

Comment: @Welbog I don't think he has any examples and also I checked the "data structure and algorithm in java by goodrich" book but I didn't found any examples... Anyway I think this answer would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098054/finding-maximum-input-time-complexity

Comment: That referred to answer makes the same mistake that your teacher apparently makes. You cannot say anything about the running times for some specific inputs, even if you have the results for a few other samples. Big O only tells us something about asymptotic behaviour, but nothing about the running times for some sample inputs (or about the input size for some sample running times). It is possible that an algo has some very unintuitive execution times for input sizes below a million, and only above that threshold follows the nlogn "pattern". That threshold could be anywhere.

Comment: You've already been told that the question is poorly written, but that doesn't help you finish the assignment. So I'll rephrase the question for you in a way that *is* solvable (and IMO, is probably what your teacher intended). Given `t = K nlogn` with `t=.0005` and `n=100`, solve for `K`. Then using that `K` and `t=60`, solve for `n`.

Answer (score 1):

following the OP's comment

> n^n = 2^(12*10^6)

It comes from :
0.5/6000 = log2(100^100)/log2(n^n)

Considering `n^n - 10^12000000` as Equation [1]

| `n` | `Equation [1]` result is.. | next `n` should be.. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | -ve (< 0) | bigger |
| 1000000 | -ve | bigger |
| 10000000 | +ve | [smaller](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000000%5E10000000-10%5E12000000) |
| average(10^6,10^7)=5500000 | +ve | smaller |
| average(10^6,550000)=3250000 | +ve | smaller |
| average(10^6,325000)=2125000 | +ve | smaller |
| average(10^6,212500)=1562500 | -ve | bigger |
| average(212500,1562500)=1843750 | -ve | bigger |
| average(212500,1847500)=1984375 | +ve | smaller |
| 1914062.5 | +ve | [smaller](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1914062.5%5E1914062.5-10%5E12000000) |
| 1878906.25 | -ve | bigger |
| 1896484.375 | -ve | bigger |
| 1905273.438 | -ve | bigger |
| 1909667.969 | -ve | bigger |
| 1911865.234 | +ve | smaller |
| 1910766.602 | +ve | smaller |
| 1910217.285 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910491.943 | +ve | smaller |
| 1910354.614 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910423.279 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910457.611 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910474.777 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910483.36 | +ve | smaller |
| 1910479.069 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910481.215 | +ve | smaller |
| 1910480.142 | -ve | bigger |
| 1910480.678 | +ve | smaller |
| 1910480.41 | -ve | bigger |

In the 2nd row, I try 100000 coz 100 (with 2 '0's) leads to 10^200 (2 '0's at the exponent) . So 12000000 (with 2 '0's) seems fair to try 1000000 (with 6 '0's). Since n should be bigger, I try 10^7 on the 3rd row.

But in 4th row and above, the logic is find the bigger/smaller number within the previously identified boundary..

I stopped at `1910480.41` the iteration already oscillates.  Thus the calculated answer is `1910480`.

If we want to test whether `1910480` suits.. continue the above iteration until the difference(in `Equation [1]`)/accuracy satisfies the end user.

Please ask should there is anything to clarifies.

p/s: the removed (edited) answer is correct if the Time Complexity is O(n). Btw, the above method executes some sort of [Bisection Method](http://mathforcollege.com/nm/mws/gen/03nle/mws_gen_nle_txt_bisection.pdf).

Comment: right but I can't solve that equation because n^n will appear

Comment: where? mind sharing that equation steps with us?

Comment: so in you're equation x will be 12,000,000 but in the question, it says time complexity is O(nlogn) and n represents input data. So the question will be "find n if nlogn = 12*10^6" . and it also can be written as "n^n = 2^(12*10^6)"

Comment: thanks but I don't think that's what the designer of the question means bc it just becomes a mathematics question.

Comment: Feel free to edit the details in the answer. I'm more than happy if someone can include the question insights in it.. /(^_^)